# Why does ` ->setStatusCode(422)` change response laravel

Tags: laravel, http

So basically I have been working on a simple upload system with laravel.
But the problem now is request validation.I am trying to check  whether the upload fits some requirements.If it doesn't,

- send a http status code of 422(meaning unprocessable entity)  and
- send the validator errors e.g `Title field is required`.

The problem is that I can't get it to do **both**.

If I use this code(with `->setStatusCode(422)` ):

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) 
{




        return back()
    ->withInput()
    ->setStatusCode(422)
    ->withErrors($request->validator->errors());
        //return back()->withError($request->validator->errors())->setStatusCode(422);


}
```

It sends the correct status code **but does not send the errors** It only shows this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image">http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

.....whatever that means.

But if I omit the `->setStatusCode(422)`(or comment it out) in the code as :

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) 
{




        return back()
    ->withInput()
    //->setStatusCode(422)
    ->withErrors($request->validator->errors());
        //return back()->withError($request->validator->errors())->setStatusCode(422);


}
```

It sends the correct validator errors but sends a `200`(OK) http status code  which is not what I want.

Please any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The `back` helper has a default status of `302` as the first argument, if you want the 422: `return back(422)`

Comment: `InvalidArgumentException
The HTTP status code is not a redirect ("422" given).
`

Comment: Symfony defines the following redirect status codes: `201, 301, 302, 303, 307, 308`. If the status code is not one of the ones defined, you will receive that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`back()` returns a redirect response. A redirect response has a status of code between 300 and 399 (typically it's 301 or 302) . A browser will only follow a redirect if the response status is between 300 and 399.

What you should do is not change the status code at all because the validation error happens in page X and you redirect back to page Y. If Page Y does not cause any errors so you should not show an outdated status code. There was an error but now you're somewhere else. It is too late for displaying errors.

An alternative is not not redirect at all and instead show an error page with the correct status code here with a link that can optionally take the user back.